# List sorting in Python

Tags: python, sorting

I have to sort a list such that list[0] < list[1] > list[2] < list[3] > list[5]...

Example: Input [1,7,2,1,3,5] O/p: [1,5,2,3,1,7]
Input: [5,2,9,8,7, 11, 1] O/p: [2,9,1,11,5,8,7]

```
#sort the array
arr.sort()

# Swap adjacent elements
for i in range(0,n-1,2):
    arr[i], arr[i+1] = arr[i+1], arr[i]
```

This one is close but inaccurate

I tried a lot but couldn't understand how those sample outputs came in that order as multiple solutions are possible.

I first sorted followed by some trials.
Can someone give an explanation

Comment: I don't get the sorting algorithm, can you elaborate?

Comment: What are the rules of the algorithm? Examples don't really make it clear, unfortunately

Comment: Yes that's what I thought. Had this one in a test. But they only provided this much. Basically the odd numbered elements should be greater than elements on both sides of them

Comment: Are those inequalities really `<` rather than `<=`? Because if the list can contain duplicates, it's much easier to allow the equal values to be next to one another, and in for some inputs, it may be necessary (e.g. a list with *only* duplicates). Also, it's not clear how the operators are supposed to chain. Is `list[0]` supposed to be less than `list[2]` (like it would be in a normal sort), not just `list[1]`? Python has chaining rules, but they may not be the ones intended by your instructor.

Comment: I'm not sure this has an exact solution, couldn't you get more than one correct answer for some sequences?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't get the exact same output as you're expecting, but meets the sorting conditions

```
arr = [5,2,9,8,7, 11, 1]
#sort the array
arr.sort()

for i in range(0, len(arr)-1):
    if(i % 2 != 0):
        arr[i], arr[i+1] = arr[i+1], arr[i]
print(arr)
```

Comment: Instead of using a mod test, why not just use `range(1, len(arr)-1, 2)`?

Comment: Doesn't work, fails for example `arr = [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]`. You end up with `[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]`.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: I'm not sure the problem is well defined for all inputs if the inequalities are strict (`<` rather than `<=`). There's no possible valid answer for `[1,1,1]` for instance.

Comment: @Blckknght Well likely it's guaranteed that a valid answer exists, see for example the "Note" here: https://leetcode.com/problems/wiggle-sort-ii/description/

Answer (score 0):

#### With a `for-loop`:

First `sort()` the `list` as you have done. Then `loop` the starting `index` of the `pairs` to switch. You need to loop from `1` to the `length - 2` so that `list[0] < list[1]`. If you start at `index` `0`, then the result will be `list[0] > list[1] < list[2] ...` which is **not** what your requirement states for the algorithm's output.

The code below should `implement` it correctly for the lists that can be `sorted` in this way.

```
arr = [5, 2, 9, 8, 7, 11, 1]

arr.sort()    
for i in range(1, len(arr)-2, 2):
   arr[i], arr[i+1] = arr[i+1], arr[i]
```

which gives:

```
[1, 5, 2, 8, 7, 9, 11]
```

*N.N. as pointed out in the comments, the `<` should really be `<=` and the `>`, `>=` in the description as for certain `input` `lists`, the sorting algorithm cannot be applied.*

Comment: Your final result `[1, 5, 2, 8, 7, 9, 11]` is invalid, as 9 isn't larger than 11.

Comment: @StefanPochmann lol, just realized better scrap that solution!

Comment: Also, where was it pointed out that it should be `<=` and `>=`? I only see Blckknght *asking* about it. And in the comments under Asthmatic's answer I linked to a possible source of the problem, where it really does use `<` and `>`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to sort your list, split it into high values and low values, and simply zip them together.

```
import itertools

def weirdsort(lst):
    lst.sort()
    pivot = len(lst) // 2
    lowers = lst[:pivot]
    highers = lst[pivot:]

    return list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(lowers, highers)))
```

As mentioned in the comments, the sorting rules given allow for more than one correct answer. This produces `weirdsort([1,7,2,1,3,5]) -> [1,3,1,5,2,7]`, which still satisfies `list[0] < list[1] > list[2] < list[3] > list[5]`

Comment: Fails for example `[1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1]`, returning `[1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2]`